# What's this housefly-like bug?

Tags: species-identification

[image: Sticky fly]

When it flies around it looks like a slightly lazy housefly.
About a centimeter long.
Has a pointy beak (slightly blurred here by the shadow).
Loves flying at people. Tickly when it sits on you. Hard to brush off - clings on hard. Very resilient - you can swat it a couple of times and nothing will happen.
Makes a crunch when properly squashed. Sighted in central Israel (Beit Shemesh).
What is it?

Comment: it is a louse fly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippoboscidae they bite and the wound can take several months to heal completely.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks @trondhansen !

Comment: BTW Your reference points to another reference that says this particular type is a Pigeon fly and a further reference says that they will not normally bite humans unless they can't find their regular host (pigeons) around - and there are lots of those here! Also says that if desperate enough to bite humans, their bites are just "itchy".

Comment: i know too little about them to make an answer,one of the types we have here is the deer louse fly and they bite many types of mamals including humans,i live in norway but the deer louse fly is common in most areas where one can find deer-roe deer-moose.